# CSS: modulo-like behavior without modulo or stepped functions

Tags: css, math, modulo

The environment I'm working with doesn't support CSS functions like mod(), round() or rem(). abs() and sign() are also not supported. However, max(), min() and clamp() are supported.

What I need is a workaround to achieve the behavior of a function f(a,b) that does the following: If a < b, return a. If a >= b, return 0. So basically, I need something that works like min(a,b), except when a >= b, it returns 0 instead of b.

I'm only dealing with positive integers. It doesn't matter what negative numbers would do.

If I could use mod(), then I could simply do mod(min(a,b),b) to get what I want.

Comment: pixel value or integer?

Comment: pixel value, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clamp()`

```css
.box {
   --a: 20px;
   --b: 40px;
   --f: clamp(0px,(var(--b) - var(--a))*1000,var(--a));
   /* 
     if a < b --> (b-a)*1000 a big positive value clamped to a
     if a > b --> (b-a)*1000 a negative value clamped to 0
    */
    
   width: var(--f);
   border:2px solid red;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--b: 10px"></div>
```

If it's integer, remove the unit:

```css
.box {
   --a: 20;
   --b: 40;
   --f: clamp(0,(var(--b) - var(--a))*1000,var(--a));
   /* 
     if a < b --> (b-a)*1000 a big positive value clamped to a
     if a > b --> (b-a)*1000 a negative value clamped to 0
    */
    
   width: calc(var(--f)*1px);
   border:2px solid red;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--b: 10"></div>
```

Comment: This is pretty good, but it has a small drawback: I think relying on multiplying by a large number leads to some animation glitches, presumably because the animation has trouble smoothly calculating the inbetween-values.

Comment: @sonofevil what animation?

Comment: When the size of something changes in CSS, (for example from 30px to 50px,) by default there is a short shrinking or growing animation where the object goes through the intermediate steps (31px, 32px, 33px etc.).

Well, in Firefox anyway.

Comment: No, nevermind, it was caused by something completely unrelated.